# How to create a function that reacts to what a previous function generated in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, math, feedback

- I created two functions (`F1` and `F2`)
- `F1` creates a random answer
- `F2` should give Feedback to the answer `F1` generated (`if(antw == ant`)
- My question is how can I make `F2` work with the random answer `F1`
  generated, so that the Feedback is correct?

```js
var operators = ['+','-'];

function F1()
{    
   Z1 = document.getElementById("Z1");
     Z2 = document.getElementById("Z2");
     oper=document.getElementById("operator");
     answer=document.getElementById("answer");
     
        rZ1 = Math.floor((Math.random()*10));
     rZ2 = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
     op = operators[Math.floor(Math.random()*2)];
     
        Z1.innerHTML=rZ1;
     Z2.innerHTML=rZ2;
     oper.innerHTML=op;
     answer.innerHTML = eval(rZ1 + op + rZ2);      
}

document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", F2);

function F2()
{
 antw = parseInt(document.getElementById("userAnswer").value, 10);
 feedBack = document.getElementById("feedBack");
 ant = document.getElementById("answer");

 {
 if(antw == ant) {
 feedBack.textContent = "right";

 } else {
 feedBack.textContent = "wrong";
 }
}  
};
```

```html
<button onclick="F1()"> New </button>

<p> 
     <label id="Z1"> </label> 
     <label id="operator"> </label>
    <label id="Z2"> </label>
      = <input id = "userAnswer" type=text>
        <button id = "button2" >answer</button>
</p>   

<p id = "feedBack"> </p>

<p><label id="answer"> </label></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call F2 at the end of the function F1 and pass the answer to F2 as a parameter.

```
function F2(answer){
    //logic to check answer
    return feedback
}

function F1(){
   //logic to calculate answer
   F2(answer)
}
```

You can use your original code, only need to fix a small problem in your code. You forgot to use textContent to get the value from your html, so you are comparing undefined value with your answer

```
ant = document.getElementById("answer").textContent;
```

Comment: I tried this out now but the feedback is still "wrong" even though it should respond "right". @colin Can you for example edit it directly in the given code, so that I can follow better what you mean.